# How to make grey text on a textbox that disapears in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am searching for the same answer that was given here:
[HTML/CSS Making a textbox with text that is grayed out, and disappears when I click to enter info, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681036/html-css-making-a-textbox-with-text-that-is-grayed-out-and-disappears-when-i-cl)

But I want to do this in MVC4.

I got the following view:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Kompetens", "KumaAdmin"))
            {  
                <div class="three columns" style="margin-right: 627px;">
                    <h6>Kompetens</h6>
                    <div style="width:456px;"> @Html.ListBox("kompetensId", (SelectList)ViewBag.KomId)</div><br/>
                    <h6>Lägg till kompetens</h6>
                    <div class="focus">
                    @Html.EditorFor(mm => mm.KompetensTest)
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" style="margin-right: 205px;" value="Skapa"/><br/><br/>
                </div>
             }
```

Since this is my textbox:

```
@Html.EditorFor(mm => mm.KompetensTest)
```

I don't know how to apply the "onfocus" & onblur attributes on it like in  the link above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the placeholder html attribute (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp)

Something like `@Html.EditorFor(mm => mm.KompetensTest, new { placeholder = "Text" })`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an Editor Template. Because the Html.EditorFor does not have the "object htmlattributes" parameter to do "new { onfocus = "js here" }".

Over the Views>Shared,

Create a folder called EditorTemplates

Then, you create a view using @model string/whathever this object is. Name the file as you want.

When you put the @model on a view you are specifying that it only accepts this type mas a model.

Inside this view, you create a Html.TextBox (not TextBoxFor) and voila.

On the Html.EditorFor method there is also a way to set which editor template you want to use. Choose the one you created by typing its name like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(mm => mm.KompetensTest, "GreyedTemplate")
```

Code for the View I named as: GreyedTemplate.cshtml

```
@model string

@Html.TextBox("", Model, new { onfocus = "", onclick="" })
```

Note that the first parameter is empty. This was done on purpose, because when you use EditorFor(mm => mm.KompetensTest,"GreyedTemplate") it uses KompetensTest as the name of the field automatically.

Comment: I am experimenting with this, will respond shortly if it works.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Gmoliv It worked finaly! I googeld arround and found that the "Editfor" does not have access to html attributes. Although I found "TextBoxFor" which has access to them, so the soloution is:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(mm => mm.Profile, new { placeholder = "Ange Profil" })
```

@Pedro I really tried hard to make it work but the problem was that i could not get the value to be set so it was alwasy empty, i treid setting it in the view and in the templateView and it simply did not take. If you could i would appreciate a full code sample

Thanks alot!